# Weblogic 12c data source high count connection

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, datasource, jndi

So, we have already deploying an application, which consist a heavy business logic that my company uses. After some time, the performance was quite slower than before, actually in the weblogic data source configuration, we set the maximum connection to only 100, but recently it keeps on increasing until its limit.

We reconfigure the data source to 200, but it keeps on increasing, this is not ideal, because 100 is the max connection that we want it to be deployed.

[image: high count]

Meanwhile, there were some thread stuck in the server too. But i think it's not the problem. Do someone knows why is this occuring so suddenly? (after implementation of a newer yet stable version, they said)

Comment: Generally that has to do with transactions that take too long or using connections without transaction and not returning them to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot attached I can see that Active Connection Count is ~80. Also I can see connection are being leaked.

1. Enable Inactive Connection Timeout by defining some value (Based on avg time taken to execute statement).
2. Make sure that all JDBC connections are closed in your code after using it.